# Verb + Preposition - use of from

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have a cylinder and a nail. If an instruction says 'the nail is inserted from the top' what is the correct meaning? Does the verb refer to the cylinder or the nail?

Comment: A bit more context would be handy. For example, does the *head* of the nail fit inside the cylinder? Are there any other components? Do they all fit together in such a way that there's automatically a "top" and "bottom" to whatever you're in the process of assembling?

Comment: There are only 2 components, both of which could be considered to have a "top" and a "bottom". The head of the nail can fit inside the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that "is inserted" is a passive verb with the nail as the subject and 'from the top' functions as an adverb describing how the insertion occurs. Imagining the sentence with an explicit object makes this a little clearer: "the nail is inserted (into the cylinder) from the top (of the cylinder)"

Comment: That is my understanding as to the intended meaning too, however with no explicit object mentioned, could this (correctly) be taken to also mean the other way around - eg "the nail is inserted from the top (of the nail)"

Comment: I'm not sure that the verb insert can be used to say "insert a thing from the top of itself." Idiomatically the phrase "from the top (of a song)" can mean "starting at the beginning and proceeding towards the end" but I think that idiom does not extend to spatial relationships between objects. If constructing an object with a top/bottom or front/back one would insert and attach things to the main object with the directions being referent to the orientation of the main object (e.g. 'start painting from the top of the model boat').

Comment: I would say the instructions are badly written - firstly, it should be *"the nail is inserted **into** the top [of the cylinder]"*, and secondly, if the nail can be inserted either head or point first the instructions should make clear *which way round it goes in*. But there's not really much point in trying to analyse such a flawed unclear/ambiguous construction. Having said that, note that you can of course *fill a tank **from** the top or bottom*.